# AWS SQS dead letter queues, if two messages have exact same string, will the second message be considered a reattempt of the first message?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

Regarding AWS SQS dead letter queues, if two messages have the exact same string, will the second message be considered a reattempt of the first message?

So like if I put retry attempts as 2, would the second message count as the retry event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazon SQS does not look at the 'content' of messages.

Message retry counts would be based on the message's 'metadata' itself (with a unique ID supplied by AWS) rather than the content of the message.